# protocol exception was unhandled wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, exception

The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:Result. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type ServiceApplication.WebResult. The maximum string content 
**Server Web.Config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing"
        propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="F:\WCFLoadBalance\ClientApplication\ServiceApplication\bin\web_tracelog.svclog"
        type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
        name="ServiceListener" traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack, DateTime, Timestamp, ProcessId, ThreadId, Callstack">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ServiceBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="16" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2000000" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="ServiceApplication.Service1" />
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CrystalEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/CrystalModel.csdl|res://*/CrystalModel.ssdl|res://*/CrystalModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=FLEMIN\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyCrystal;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>

**Client App.config..**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text"
                    textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="16" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:54958/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ClientServiceReference.IService1"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I think he/she wants to know how to resolve that exception

Comment: Yes Thanks for ur responses i need that solution for that exception..

Answer (score 2):

What about your client configuration file?

> There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:Result.

Since the error occurred while deserializing a result, probably it was on the client side.

Try increasing the value of the maxStringContentLength attribute in your client configuration file.  Or at least post your client configuration file.